# How to stretch the corners of this image so that it looks like a perfect rectangle?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, sketch-app, transform, distort

I have an image that I took at an angle, so it isn't a perfect rectangle:

[image]

How would I pull the bottom left and bottom right corners in so that they line up perfectly with the top two corners?

Like this:

[image]

I have both Photoshop and Sketch.

Comment: One is left: How do I make the background look out cotton fabric and all colored and black shapes look out like they were embroidered?

Comment: The best way to fix this is to retake the photo at a perpendicular angle (90°) to the surface being photographed. The answers given suggesting the correction of the perspective in Photoshop will certainly work, but they will degrade the image quality slightly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Photoshop there's a filter to fix those lens distortions:

- Menu Filter → Lens Correction

Choose the top **Custom** tab and modify the **Vertical Perspective** and **Scale**

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As Sergey mentioned, perspective crop is your tool-of-choice here:

As we prefer here at **GD.SE** to answer live versus dropping links, I'll do a quick set of screengrabs for you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hopefully you get the idea...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Perspective Crop tool in Photoshop: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/crop-straighten-photos.html#transform_perspective_while_cropping

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have Photoshop, the app [Office Lens](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/microsoft-office-lens-pdf-scan/id975925059?mt=8) will do this.

You can either use it to take the photo directly, or load in a photo from your camera roll (the latter is the method you want).

1. Open the app and tap the gallery icon

   [image]
2. Select your photo. It will try to auto-fit. This can be very accurate. For my image, it was not. Tap the Edit Points button:

   [image]
3. Drag the points to where you want them, and then tap done:

   [image]
4. The finished image:

   [image]

The app is also available for iPad (and Android) which provides a somewhat easier editing experience.